# Как перенаправлять пользователя в определённую папку на хостинге

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess

Разрабатывал MVP проекта у себя на локальном хостинге. Все ссылки делал абсолютными, вида "/", "/admin.php", "/handler/admin-handler.php".

Пришло время выложить на хостинг. Но так как пока это MVP, решили выложить его на уже существующем хостинге и домене лендинга. А проект поместить в отдельную папку. Поэтому абсолютные ссылки в проекте теперь должны выглядеть как "/project_folder/", "/project_folder/admin.php", "/project_folder/handler/admin-handler.php".

Ссылок в проекте много, переделывать долго. Можно ли настроить .htaccess так, чтобы все ссылки переделывались из "/" в "/project_folder/", "/admin.php" в "/project_folder/admin.php" и т.д.?
Или перестать лениться и переписать вручную?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html

Comment: во избежание подобного, ссылки надо не прямиком в код прописывать, а использовать какой-нибудь роутинг, в котором в дальнейшем просто было прописать используемый префиск.

Comment: еще вариант сделать не папку, а поддомен, куда более удобное решение

Comment: Можете, конечно, и с помощью `RewriteRule` переправить обработку всех входящих запросов в эту папку (про что вы собственно и спрашиваете), но что-то мне кажется, что это несколько не то, что вам нужно. а-ля `RewriteRule ^admin\.php folder\admin.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: @teran Спасибо, перенес проект на поддомен.

Answer (score -1):

> Или перестать лениться и переписать вручную?

А что вы используете в качестве IDE или редактора, блокнот?

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: будет работать, до тех пор пока в качестве значения не стоит переменная, и определенно не обработает js скрипты, например, или css.

Comment: @teran Данный реплейс ищет все вхождения искомой строки и заменяет на необходимый, не понял вашего комментария, почему должны возникнуть проблемы с js и css...
Я отредактировал, можете еще раз взглянуть на скрин.

Comment: потому что он не затронет строк вида PHP: `<a href=<?= 'admin.php' ?>`, JS: `location.href = 'admin.php'`, CSS: `background: url(/img/bg.png)` и еще множество вариантов.

Comment: @teran `<a href=<?= 'admin.php' ?>` - это вообще что, боюсь спросить? 
В остальном, если вы имеете в виду, что все заменить именно за одну операцию не получится, то это уже другой разговор, но можно приложить толику усилий и сделать три замены, отдельно для php, css, js файлов, однако, нужно знать, как у автора реализованы данные тонкости.

Но, если же вы имеете в виду, что данный реплейсер не сможет по каким-либо причинам распарсить определенные скрипты для замены, хотелось бы увидеть больше уточнений с вашей стороны, т.к. он ищет вхождения и меняет их в коде, как в обычной строке.

Comment: я думаю, что изначально идея писать вручную ссылки в коде  был весьма плоха. В связи с этим, исправлять эти ссылки вручную, не решив собственно проблемы, это очередной костыль, который ни чуть не лучше исходной проблемы.

Comment: @teran Естественно, я полностью с вами согласен.